# How can I center the scrollable tab?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

There are 3 tabs and I could not center them on the screen. How can I center the scrollable tab? As of now, it will only be on the left side of the screen

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-dbcxl?file=/demo.js

Below are the codes:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Tabs from "@mui/material/Tabs";
import Tab from "@mui/material/Tab";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";

export default function ScrollableTabsButtonAuto() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <Tabs
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      variant="scrollable"
      scrollButtons="auto"
      aria-label="scrollable auto tabs example"
      centered
    >
      <Tab label="Item One" />
      <Tab label="Item Two" />
      <Tab label="Item Three" />
    </Tabs>
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you send your code into the codepan or sandbox ? so other can help you as fast as can？

Comment: @screwspike added it already. thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is because the container of the Tabs has the same width as the Tabs.

You should be able to wrap the Tabs component with a [Box](https://mui.com/components/box/#main-content) which has full width.

For example,

```
<Box display="flex" justifyContent="center" width="100%">
  <Tabs ...>
  ...
  </Tabs>
</Box>
```

Comment: Glad that helped.